# The Bochner integral about a semigroup of bounded linear operators on a Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, integration, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Let $T(t)$ be a semigroup of bounded linear operators on a Banach space $X$. When does the following hold
$$
\int_0^t T(s)x ds = \Big(\int_0^t T(s) ds\Big)x, \quad x \in X \, ,
$$
where $ t \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Almost never. The operator valued function is in general not measurable (only if the generator is bounded).

Answer (score 7):

Following ideas of John von Neumann,

*J. von Neumann*, [**Über einen Satz von Herrn M. H. Stone**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1968535), Ann. Math. (2) 33, 567-573 (1932). [ZBL0005.16402](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0005.16402),

it can be shown that if a function satisfies the semigroup law and is measurable, then it is already continuous. Hence your identity is only true if the generator is bounded.

See also

*Engel, Klaus-Jochen; Nagel, Rainer*, [**One-parameter semigroups for linear evolution equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/b97696), Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 194. Berlin: Springer. xxi, 586 p. (2000). [ZBL0952.47036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0952.47036)., Exercise I.1.7.(2).

Comment: Thanks. If $T(t)$ is a  uniformly contiouous semigroup, then the identity is true. Right?

Comment: Yes. But then, the identity of the right-hand side is also just a Riemann integral of a continuous function. In that case, the generator is a bounded operator, which is almost never satisfied in relevant applications.